# Get existing item count comparing two table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL database.

**machine_tbl**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      section        |     machine      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-001     |   AT-TWB-001     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-001     |   AT-TWB-002     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-001     |   AT-TWB-003     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-001     |   AT-TWB-004     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-002     |   AT-TWB-005     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-002     |   AT-TWB-006     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    2400-TWO-003     |   AT-TWB-007     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**open_notification_tbl**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      user           |     machine      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a1               |   AT-TWB-001     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a1               |   AT-TWB-001     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a2               |   AT-TWB-001     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a3               |   AT-TWB-002     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a1               |   AT-TWB-002     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a4               |   AT-TWB-003     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a4               |   AT-TWB-004     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

What I want is to get *machine count* for specific *section* comparing these two tables.

For example section 2400-TWO-001 has 3 AT-TWB-001 machines, section 2400-TWO-001 has 2 AT-TWB-002 machines. Like wise. If no machine is there then count should be zero. I am then creating a JSON according to that using php.

**Query...**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.section, a.machine, count(b.user) AS countX FROM machine_tbl AS a LEFT JOIN open_notification_tbl AS b ON a.machine= b.machine WHERE section = ?
```

Comment: Try executing the posted query and let us know the issue you have ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.machine) AS countX
FROM machine_tbl m LEFT JOIN
     open_notification_tbl o
     ON m.machine = o.machine
WHERE section = ?;
```